# Why does an executable built with crosstool-ng not work on a Pi 3B with 64-bit Raspbian?

Tags: cross-compilation

I've just tried out `crosstool-ng` on my Linux PC to compile C++ apps for my Pi 3B much quicker than on the Pi itself. I followed [this instruction](https://www.nayab.xyz/rpi3b-elinux/embedded-linux-rpi3-010-toolchain.html), but executing the dummy program as stated in the instruction always leads to this error when trying to run it on the Pi:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ ./dummy
-bash: ./dummy: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

This is my Raspbian version:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ uname -a
Linux autoradio 5.4.83-v7+ #1379 SMP Mon Dec 14 13:08:57 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

This is the format of my executable:

```
pi@autoradio:/import/valen/autoradio $ file dummy
dummy: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 5.4.21, with debug_info, not stripped
```

…and this is the `crosstool-ng` version on my host:

```
╭─jacek@epica /opt/crosstool-ng  ‹75d7525a*› 
╰─➤  aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu-gcc --version
aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu-gcc (crosstool-NG 1.24.0.103_75d7525) 9.2.0
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: you've compiled for `ARM aarch64` - but you're running `armv7l` - i.e. you're NOT running 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS

Comment: Jaromanda is correct, look more closely at the output of `uname -a`.

Comment: So, would have `armv7l-rpi3-linux-gnu` been the correct architecture?